# Implementing web service security in Reporting Tools

Tags: web-services, web-applications, http-headers, http-referer

I have a web reporting tool lets say Business Objects, Cognos, OBIEE, Crystal Reports. I want to display some data into the report which is coming from a Web Service. So i copy paste the Web service URL inside the report cell and i can access the data.

However this leaves a big security issue as i cannot authenticate the requestor. One thing which i can think of is checking the Http header request: referer property which is set by the reporting tool in my Web Service. This atleast ensures that the request has originated from my Reporting Application. Besides this i cannot see how i can authenticate a specific user.

Appending Username in the Web Service URL is also not an option because one report is used by many users. I would somehow want to access this specific user session and associate the web service request with this user session. Lets say both my Web Reporting tool and web service are running on the same Web Application Server. Is it possible to merge the Web Service Provider and my Reporting Application so that the session user name is available in the WebService ?